# app-relative paths in url() in dotless

Tags: asp.net, css, dotless

I have a bunch of .less files that contain image backgrounds:

```
.header {
    background-image:url(~/images/some_image.png);
}
```

In debug mode, these .less files are served directly, but in release mode they're served as a part of a bundle.  The path depths between the bundle URL and the individual file URLs are not always the same, so I can't just use relative URLs.

The default options for the dotless nuget package do not parse app-relative paths. Is there an option to make it do the right thing?

Comment: URLs in CSS files are already relative to the path of the CSS file.  Is that not enough?

Comment: good question - question updated to answer it.  I want to be able to serve the .less files from a bundle with a different path depth in release configuration.

Comment: This is difficult since `~` has a different meaning in less syntax. (literal string)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** There is a potentially fatal flaw in this approach.  The `apppath.less` file has to be in a certain location which isn't necessarily known, which creates a chicken-egg scenario.  Still, it may be helpful to some extent.

One approach is to use an `@import` rule that declares a variable containing the app path like this:

```
@import "apppath.less"
```

If you can't use a .less extension, you should be able to use `(less)` to force .less interpretation.

```
@import (less) "apppath.ashx"
```

Instead of being a static file, apppath.less could simply use `Response.Write` to echo the application path, producing an output like this:

```
@app-path: "http://yourserver/app/path";
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
.header {
    background-image:url("@{app-path}/images/some_image.png");
}
```